# phpStorm не выгружать файлы ftp по маске

Tags: phpstorm, ftp, маска

Есть проект на ftp. Перед началом работы, обычно, выкачиваю себе проект на локальный компьютер используя phpStorm.

1. Есть ли возможность исключить из скачивания файлы по маске? (например для работы мне картинки не нужны и смысла выкачивать все *.png, *.jpg и *.gif - не нужно)
2. Есть возможность сделать ограничение по скорости закачки в шторме?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `settings - build - deployment - option` <- тут есть поле `exclude items by name` в котором можно написать расширения файлов.
2. `settings - build - deployment` <- исключением папок (например если картинки в папке images) в `excluded paths`